# Finding Best Linear Unbiased Estimator

Tags: regression, estimation, unbiased-estimator, blue, gauss-markov-theorem

[image]

I have the doubt that if Gauss Markov theorem is applicable here since the Variance is not constant in the model. Without Gauss Markov Theorem, how can we obtain BLUE?

Comment: Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares

Comment: I know about GLSE or Weighted Least Squares Estimators but they are difficult to compute. I thought there could be some simpler way to solve this problem.

Comment: Just minimize variance of $\sum c_iY_i$ subject to $E[\sum c_iY_i]=\theta$. See similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3433326/321264.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Cauchy–Schwarz inequality is a smart way of solving this problem. Thanks!

Comment: If you have solved the problem you can post an answer.

Comment: I did but they did it too - [MVUE](https://www.cheenta.com/isi-mstat-psb-2004-problem-6-unbiased-minimum-variance-estimators/)